# I need to sort hundreds of information with their prices using Python 3(VS Code) but they come from a txt document and not too similar to each other

Tags: python, python-3.x

- Red Shoes / 8444 **0.016** Children Shoes | For Winter and Spring | **$0.016** 100 1000000
- Blue Shoes / 8458 **0.021** Children Shoes | For Winter and Spring | **0.021** 100 1000000
- Blue Shirt / 8420 **0.038** Children and Teenager Shirts | For Winter and Spring | **$0.038** 100 1000000
- Gray Boots / 8423 **0.014** Children and Teenager Boots | Suitable For Winter | **0.014** 100 1000000
- Pink Sweater / 8431 **0.030** Female Children Sweater | Winter and Spring | **0.030** 100 1000000

Greetings everyone. A novice coder here. I need to complete this project, and I have hundreds of information like these in a txt file. I tried literally everything I could but couldn't sort them properly. The bold text are price tags, and I need to sort them with price.

```
 f = open("trial1.txt")

list1= []
tuple1=()
for l in f:
    a = l.split(" ")
    list1.append(a)

tuple1 = tuple(list1)
c = tuple1[1][1]
# print(c.split(" "))
c = sorted(tuple1, key = lambda tuple1: tuple1[1])
print(c)

g = []
h=()
for l in c:
    print(l)
    l2 = l[4].split(" ")
    print(l2[0])
    g.append(l2[0])
    h = tuple(g)
j = sorted(g, key = lambda g: g[0])    
print(j)
```

I'm stuck here, I could have sorted the prices but only prices. I'm at a serious confusion point. Any help or suggestion is much appreciated.

Edit: I also tried numpy to sort arrays, but that didn't work out for me either. I know I'm doing something wrong but can't figure out what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make list of lists from every line , then sort those lines by price from inner list price index.

```
s = '''Red Shoes / 8444 0.016 Children Shoes | For Winter and Spring | $0.016 100 1000000
Blue Shoes / 8458 0.021 Children Shoes | For Winter and Spring | 0.021 100 1000000
Blue Shirt / 8420 0.038 Children and Teenager Shirts | For Winter and Spring | $0.038 100 1000000
Gray Boots / 8423 0.014 Children and Teenager Boots | Suitable For Winter | 0.014 100 1000000
Pink Sweater / 8431 0.030 Female Children Sweater | Winter and Spring | 0.030 100 1000000'''

lines = [[*line.split(" ")] for line in s.split('\n')]
res = sorted(lines, key=lambda line: line[4])
print(res)
s = ""
for line in res:
    s += " ".join(line) + '\n'

print(s)
```

Comment: This works like a charm tbh. Thank you! Still, it does not work for all the information. I think encoding affects this, some lines has special characters like emojis so I open it as utf8 and it messes up stuff :(

Comment: So `open(f, encoding="utf-8")` does not work? Strange. Try finding out the file encoding then (UTF-16 maybe?) using a detection program.

Comment: I've recreated every single file and now it reads that file with  open(f, encoding ="utf-8") but does not sort by price. Tried changing the indexes, but doesn't work for that file. It does work for ones without emoji characters though

Comment: have you tried to open it iwth open(f, encoding="utf-16")?

Comment: I'm going to try it. I'll write down the further consequences

Comment: UTF-16 seems to be working! I've concluded several files, it seems to working smoothly so far. At first it raised an error about utf-16-le but after recreating every single file it started to worl. I'll return with further notice, thank you ^^